# Framework issue during deployment

Tags: asp.net

I am getting the following error during deployment of a web application. In my deployment environment, I have an existing application that uses .NET 2.0 as application pool. The appl that I am trying to add is .NET 4.0 application. If i change the target .NET framework for Application pool for existing app to 4.0, it stops working. How can i resolve this issue?

Thanks
Jay

Line 20:             Set explicit="true" to force declaration of all variables.
Line 21:         -->
Line 22:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have another application running with another framework version you should create another application pool which uses .net 4 and assign this new app pool to your .net 4 web application. in Real World scenarios every single web app has its own app pool so they are better configurable, isolated and restartable one by one.